# Finding reverse percentage in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a problem that I'm trying to solve using JS:

> A 20% increase of ____ is 270.

How can I find the original value with a simple JS function?

I made this function, but it didn't give me the current value:

```
function percentage(total, per) {
   return (total + ((per /100) * total));
}
```

Comment: This seems like a math problem

Comment: That's simple math problem `x + (x * (20 / 100)) = 270` - solve for `x`

Comment: `x * 120/100 = 270` so, `x = 270 * 100/120`

Comment: @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth yep. Or if you want it could be `x * 1.2 = 270` so `x = 270 / 1.2`. Depends on how you want to represent the percentages.

Comment: @VLAZ considering his inputs are `270`  and `20`(%), what would be the least expensive computation to achieve the output?

Comment: @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth I honestly don't know but I also don't think it matters. I imagine that might be optimised for you by the interpreter. Just focus on whether you want to have `20`% in your code or `0.2`. Both are valid representations of the same idea, one is more useful to show to humans while the other makes it easier to do calculations because it saves you constantly converting it. Yet, you'd need to convert it for displaying. But I doubt there is any significant speed difference in terms of execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you have used can calculate the normal percentage (increase/decrease)

In case of normal percentage decrease:

```
function percentageDec(total, per) {
   return (total - ((per /100) * total));
}
```

And in case of normal percentage increase:

```
function percentageInc(total, per) {
   return (total + ((per /100) * total));
}
```

---

Your problem can be described mathematically as:

`x + (x * (20 / 100)) = 270` solve for `x`, so `x = 270 * 100/120`.

**So to implement it as a code, you can use this function (since you're trying to calculate the reverse percentage and not the normal percentage):**

```
function reversePercentage(finalNum, per) {
   return ((finalNum*100)/(per+100));
}
```

Hence:

```
reversePercentage(270, 20) // Will output: 225 <- Which's the original value
```

Now to make sure the value is correct, increase the value again with 20% using the function `percentageInc()`, so:

```
percentageInc(225, 20) // Will output: 270
```